# How do I access the top level UITabBarController to change tabs?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change tabs after the user hits the `leftBarButtonItem`. It calls a method which calls a delegate method into a parent view controller. and then in that delegate method I"m trying to change tabs.

`self.tabBarController` is `nil`. The tab bar is instantiated via a storyboard but I'm not sure how to access it now in order to change the tab bar

Any tips here?

Comment: Is it the root vc ? post your window hierarchy in an image if possible or write it with the code you tried and where

Comment: I'm a little confused. I just inherited this codebase so I'm still unpacking it. I don't have a navigationController or a tabBarController. I _think_ I have 3 tabs (I'm in the root vc of the 3rd). Normally accessing the tab bar controller is easy... Not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: extend uitabbarcontroller and put navigation logic there.

Comment: But I dont have access to the tab bar controller, how would that help?